# MySQL inheritance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, single-table-inheritance, class-table-inheritance

What would be the best way to design this MySQL database?

I have `cars`, `fuels`, and `motor oils`. Each car can use any number of `fuels` and any number of `motor oils`. What would be the best way to design this database?

So, one `car` can have one or many `fuels`, and one or many `motor oils`.

So I would need to have `cars`, `fuels`, and `motor_oils` tables in my database.
Now since `fuels` and `motor_oils` have some similar properties like price, date_produced etc.
Would it be smart for me to create another table called lets say `products`?

When using OOP language I would have `Product` entity, `Fuel` and `MotorOils` would extend `Product` and this way have properties defined in `Product`.

How would I design this in Mysql database? Is there such thing as inheritance in MySQL?
I know that relation database does not have inheritance, and that there is a way to mimic this in MySQL, just need someone to explain better how is this done?

Comment: All you can (and should) do is add foreign keys in the `fuel` and `motor_oil` tables that refer to the product in the `product` table. Seeing as, inside the database, no actual inheritance needs to be defined, there's not much else you should want to do.

Comment: No idea why this was voted down - this is a legitime question. The right database design doesn't get enough attention in many projects out there

Comment: @Patrickdev thanks! Now the problem is, how would I wrote this in my OOP language, lets say PHP. Would I have Car, Fuel, MotorOil, Products Entities? Or should I ignore Products in Entities? Write this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a products table and a foreign key in each, fuel and motor oils linking to the products table in order to have some kind of inheritance.

Many to many relationships you create by defining a mapping table with a foreign between the entities.

Given you have cars and fuels you could create a table carsFuelsMap which has two foreign key fields morors_id and fuels_id

Comment: how do you prevent a product from being both a fuel and a motor oil at the same time in that solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the delegation part of OOP in SQL using a one-to-one foreign key. So for instance a `Fuel` entry would have a foreign key to a `Product` that would identify all the shared values.

As for linking cars and fuels, this is actually a many-to-many relationship. The traditional way would use a `CarFuel` table that has one row for each valid combination of car and fuel, but as you've delegated parts of both `Fuel` and `MotorOil` to a `Product`, you probably want to use a `CarProduct` table, and if you only need fuels you can then join to the `Fuel` table.